# "I don't have the time to cook" or "I don't have time to cook"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

Should I say:

> I do not have **the** time.

Or

> I  do not have time.

Which option is the correct one? If both are correct, is there any difference in meaning or other difference between them?

Answer (score 37):

Both are fine and seem to be widely used. To me, "don't have the time" implies a long-term situation, whereas "don't have time" could be more temporary. For example, "My life is so busy that I don't have the time to cook" versus "Tonight I'm going to a concert so I won't have time to cook."

Answer (score 7):

They are both correct, and equally implied.

I don't have the time [it takes] to cook.

and

I don't have [enough] time to cook.

Both imply that you do not possess the amount of time it would take to complete the act of cooking.

Answer (score 1):

The article 'the' is used to **emphasize specificity**.

By saying, 'you don't have *time* to cook', it means you don't have time in an indefinite essence; and, by saying, 'you don't have *the time*', it means you don't have time in a specific period (in this case, during the time you said that you don't have ['the time']).

Comment: This seems backwards from the actual usage, where "the time" is more often associated with a long term situation, as [David](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/63545/9595) points out. (This lines up with my experience.) Though neither way is anywhere near an absolute.

Comment: I explained based on the sound grammar usage of the article 'the'. I did not associate my answer to either short-term or long-term situation. By saying 'indefinite' and 'definite', I simply meant that there is an implied time-frame relative to the context the speaker is in. And yes, you are correct - there is no 'absolute', unless we know the context.

Answer (score -1):

*"don't have **the** time to do x"* communicates something that's part of your personality, or a deep set habit. It doesn't refer to any specific situation. People say that when they want to say something about the kind of person they are. It says I consider act x of less important I don't want to bother myself with it.

*"don't have time to do x"* on the other hand, is very specific to a situation you are currently having. It says "Right now I am too busy with other stuff". It doesn't say anything about what kind of person you are and what habits you have.

Answer (score -2):

**have time** or not **have time** can be treated like any other verb, it means at that moment I am  (or will be) busy with other things.

> I don't have time to go there
>
> A: Will you watch TV,   B: No I **don't have time**, I must finish my homework.

However, if you say

> I don't have **the time to cook**, I usually eat fast foods

You mean that you don't have the time it takes to do a certain job or you don't like to do it, for example

> I don't have **the time to answer basic questions**. Sorry, but I need to focus on more important questions.
>
> If you don't have **the time to cook rice on normal kadai**, you can pressure cook also, but it wont be that tasty.

You don't say *I don't have the time* except to mean I don't know what time it is.